# Mapping of integration domain

Tags: integration

My question is based around the following integration which I am trying to simplify to make a code run faster:

> $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\int\limits_{\left|\frac{Ar-b}{C}\right|}^{\frac{Ar+b}{C}}
>  f(r,R) \ dR \ dr $

A and C are constants, b is a variable which can range from $0\rightarrow\infty$ and is introduced using the sifting theorem of the Dirac delta function so will just be a floating point number every integration run so can be treated as a constant.

I have not listed what the function, $f(r,R)$ is as it is far too long. My question involves mapping of the integration domain in the second integral. Rather than have algebraic domains I was attempting to map the integration domain to say -1 $\rightarrow$ 1 or any other suitable domain, i.e. make it numeric.

Is it possible with this particular integration? When I try and do it I cannot find a way to make unique limits due to the modulus being taken in the lower limit.

An example of one that I tried is:

Set $ R = \frac{r \ t +b}{C}$ this will then map the upper limit to t = A, however the lower limit cannot be processed in the same way.

Is there something obvious I am missing here as I feel this should be much simpler than I am making it out to be.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write it as $$\int_0^{b/A}\int_{\frac{b-Ar}C}^{\frac{b +Ar}C}f(r,R)\,dR\,dr+\int_{b/A}^\infty\int_{\frac{Ar-b}C}^{\frac{Ar+b}C}f(r,R)\,dR\,dr$$

Comment: Excellent, that does the trick. Thank you for your help.